# Is there folder browser widget in Gtk#?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I built UI with MonoDevelop's Gtk# UI generator and found file chooser widget but not directory/folder chooser widget. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at filechooser properties and you can choose "Select folder" from Action property.